# Haskell - trouble implementing category laws in Quickcheck

Tags: haskell

I have the category definition:

```
-- | Cat is the definition of a morphism
type Cat i = i -> i -> Type

-- | Vacuous Constraint
class Vacuous (p :: Cat i) (a :: i)
instance Vacuous p a

class Category (h :: Cat i) where
  type Ob h :: i -> Constraint
  type Ob h = Vacuous h

  id :: Ob h a => h a a
  (.) :: h b c -> h a b -> h a c
```

and I am trying to implement identity and associativity laws for it in QuickCheck, e.g.,

```
-- | Constraints
type Constraints h a b =
     (
       Category h, Ob h a,
       Arbitrary (h a b), Eq (h a b), Show (h a b)
     )

-- | Properties
prop_left_identity :: forall h a b. Constraints h a b => Property
prop_left_identity = property $ \(f:: h a b) -> f. id == f
```

Issue here is in Eq (h a b), if for instance h = (->), then I will have trouble defining Eq (a -> b) because function equality is not straightforward (I will have issue with unbounded types, and in case of bounded go through all possible inputs and I don't want that). So, I tried avoiding the point free notation and applying **f** to **a**, so I can only focus  on Eq (b), but I don't have any means to do it. I need a function `ap :: h a b -> a -> b` but compiler gives an error because b is not of kind Type.

Any ideas about this please

Comment: [`Eq (a -> b)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-reverse-instances-1.1.1/docs/Data-Universe-Instances-Eq.html)

Comment: What is the definition of `Cat`? Anyway, you're probably pretty much out of luck here. `(->)` is probably just about the *only* category for which the type you gave for `ap` makes sense. In some sense, the whole point of categories is that you don't need to think about `ap`-alikes at all (and indeed many categories have no sensible `ap`-alike of any type). You'll have to write your properties per-instance instead.

Comment: When you say “the compiler panics,” do you mean it gives a normal type error/kind error or that it literally panics? A “panic” is when the compiler actually crashes as the result of an internal bug in the compiler itself and it generates a message which says `ghc: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)`

Comment: @DavidYoung sorry I took panic from rust  and meant just an error

Comment: thanks @DanielWagner u are right. The reason I wanted to have generic properties is because I'm working on a library and I want the users to have the possibility to check if their categories are sound without having to rewrite the properties... I don't mind using "Eq (h a b)" if the check can be optimized somehow or if there is a workaround/ hack arround "ap" 